# Linux didn't installed yet but GNU grub is. How remove GNU grub?

Tags: linux, boot, multi-boot, grub, gnu

I have tried to have a dual boot in my laptop with Windows 10 and Linux. When I doing that, I could not able to complete installation process of Linux. But now I have unfinished installation part in the boot loader OS menu and it do not let me to install Linux properly. How can get rid of this problem?

Comment: Check this post on how to uninstall grub: https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader

Answer (score 0):

Grub is typically stored at the beginning of the disk/mbr - You may be able to go into Windows and rewrite the MBR][1](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-clearing-out-master-boot-record-dd-command/) - just run bootrec.exe /fixmbr and bootrec/fixmbr   (I've not done this - I don't do Windows).

To delete your mbr AND partitions -  in Linux dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=512 count = 1

[To delete your mbr only  in linux](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-clearing-out-master-boot-record-dd-command/) - dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=446 count=1